# Trigger a particular function or method everyday at a point of time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application which has many methods in it of course.. Previously i used windows task scheduler to run the application at the scheduled time. Now, I have requirement in which i have to trigger only a particular method to get the job done.  This method will be running everyday at a specified point of time.
Please help me out of this..

P.S: The method contains code to delete and archive some folders after the job is done. So there is no link with SQL and cannot use SQL Job Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass command line arguments to your application from the Task Scheduler. Based on the command line arguments you can call any specific method in your application.

[image]

Comment: That sounds fair enough.But would have been good if u could provide a small exapmle

Answer (score 0):

```
You could set the command line arguments in the application. Then you can check the value of the command line arguments and then call the appropriate function in the code.

You could do something similar to below :

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args[0] == "arg1")
            {

            }
            else if (args[0] == "arg2")
            {

            }
         }
```

you can utlilize the schedular approach only but schedule the application two times with different arguments and based on this you would be able to trigger the specific functions that you want based on condition.

Hope it helps...
Let me know if you have any issues with this...